# Parser Error of import Openzeppelin while compiling solidity code

Tags: solidity, hardhat, openzeppelin

```
Retrieving compiler information:
Compiler using remote version: 'latest', solidity version: 0.8.17+commit.8df45f5f.Emscripten.clang
ParserError: Expected string literal (path), "*" or alias list.
 --> c:/Users/manis/Desktop/React_Native/contracts/NFTMarketplace.sol:6:8:
  |
6 | import “@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol”;
  |        ^


Compilation failed with 1 errors
```

Please Tell me something about this error.

Answer (score 0):

try in your console, in the main project folder:

```
yarn add @openzeppelin/contracts
```

also, check your node_modules folder.